# 98 Ford Expedition not starting after new key?

Tags: ford, ignition-key, immobilizer, reprogram

Lost the key, used door key (not chipped) in ignition, it started then died. Replaced transponder on switch, still crank but no start. Dealer could not get new key to program, after several keys were cut and tried by dealer.

The operators manual says the Pat's can only be reset 16 times, but then says nothing else. What do I need to do to get the truck running? Replace the NAT module? The ECM? Get it flashed?

Comment: On my car, a solution is ecm, dash, keys and set of locks all replaced as a set as they are coded together. Even find sets for sale second hand on bay of fleas...

Comment: Thanks solar Mike, I was planning on doing just that,  would it eliminate the need for further programming by shop?